# A library for distributed ad-hoc state sharing?

Tags: python, distributed-computing

Generally I want to be able to synchronize order of parallel execution: to set walls and current state between unknown and chand (always more than one) amount of geterogenious workers:

```
whlie state != "end":
    if state == "blah":
        doX()
        waitAll()
        if master == True:
            state = "x"
        waitAll()
    if state == "x":
        doZ()
        waitAll()
        if master == True:
            state = "end"
        waitAll()
```

Generally I look for a way to share a state of an application in ad-hoc distributed master-slave menner. I want to have same script for master and slaves (alike in MPI model). Master have a public IP known to all slaves. Generally I see how one could implement it in ZMQ yet wonder if there is some known dedicated library for it?

Answer (score 0):

[Zookeeper](https://zookeeper.apache.org/) is built for this.  Granted we're now talking about a distributed system, that has some overhead to management.

If you're not familiar with Zookeeper you can think of it as a file-system that replicates itself across different servers running Zookeeper.  The Zookeeper 'cluster' is called an **ensemble**.

Zookeeper has primitives you can build around for distributed queues, and leader election, as well distributed locks.

Zookeeper has client libraries for many languages so it can be integrated with many different applications.

[Barrier/Queue Example](http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/trunk/zookeeperTutorial.html)

[Shared/Distributed Locks](http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/trunk/recipes.html#Shared+Locks)

Zookeeper solves some interesting problems around availability, recovery, etc through `Ephemeral` nodes.  You can write a file to **Zookeeper**, and if that connection to Zookeeper fails, or goes away, the file will automatically be deleted from Zookeeper.

You can use these Ephemeral nodes to perform service discovery as well.  Let's say you want to distribute tasks between 2, 3, 10, 100 servers.

Each server when it starts up can be given the Zookeeper connection string.  When it starts it can register itself by writing an Ephemeral file to a directory containing its IP address/port.

Through lock primitives and `ephemeral` nodes and znode versions you can implement patterns for cluster leader election.  Instead of a master/slave you can have just simply a 'cluster'. And any host in that cluster can take leadership, or be the `overseer`.

Hope this helps.